# average (x)html page per day

Tags: web-development

This question is just simple. I'm a web developer for 1 year now, particularly client-side html/css/jquery thing. I can do psd to (x)html average 3 pages per day. These pages are IE6,7,8,FF,GC,Safari,Opera compatible.

The question is, based on my experience, am I slow? What is your average number of pages per day? If you have any suggestion to make my work faster, please do.

Thanks.

Comment: Stop looking at the clock and you may work faster.

Comment: 3 pages or 3 designs? If you have built things properly with css/(x)html and the overall design is already done, then you should be completing way more than 3/day.

Comment: okay, maybe my question was so noob.

Comment: Welcome to Pro Webmasters! You might try asking one question per post, with a much less subjective topic while adequately explaining what, exactly you are doing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rate you can convert PSD to HTML is dependent on many things, including how complex the design is, browser support requirements (e.g. IE6), how much functionality is needed and of course your own expertise.

So it's impossible to judge if you are slow. If you are freelance and are earning enough money for the work you're doing then there isn't a problem.